# I have a data coming from mongo db and I want to show that data in laravel but it is unable to determine the index

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

I have printed the data in blade file.

```
{{$book}}
```

Gives :

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "59edcff8613c08eda2f01622"
    },
    "isbn": 9780071808552,
    "title": "Java: The Complete Reference",
    "author": "Herbert Schildt",
    "category": "Computing"
  }
]
```

If I do this `{{$book->title}}` error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You must [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the Json in the controller:

```
$book = json_decode($book);
```

Then you can do this without errors :

```
{{$book->title}}
```

Comment: I am doing this :
Controller:
$book = DB::collection('books')->where('_id', $id)->get();
return view('bookview')->with('book',json_decode($book));

View:

{{$book->title}}

error:

htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /var/www/html/mongo/resources/views/bookview.blade.php)

Comment: It has been solved . I have to use 

 $book = DB::collection('books')->where('_id', $id)->get()->first();